# How to dynamically redirect www-based URLs to non-www URLs with multiple domains in same VirtualHost

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've got a VirtualHost that looks something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName  domain1.com
  ServerAlias www.domain1.com domain2.com www.domain2.com

</VirtualHost>
```

When someone visits www.domain1.com/test, they should be redirected to:

```
domain1.com/test
```

When someone visits www.domain2.com/test, they should be redirected to:

```
domain2.com/test
```

My current RewriteRules are lacking.

Edit: Here's what I've got so far:

```
# Rewrite www to non-www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www\.%{HTTP_HOST}$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Obviously, this generates an infinite redirect loop.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your RewriteCond is a bit wonky.  I'm surprised it does anything at all, since it would seem to be trying to match the host `www.domain1.com` against the pattern `www\.www.domain1.com`.  These directives worked for me:

```
# Redirect www to non-www
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 10):

No need for rewrites.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias domain2.com
    ... real vhost settings ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain1.com
    Redirect permanent / http://domain1.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain2.com
    Redirect permanent / http://domain2.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: This will redirect all traffic to domain1.com, I need the traffic to remain on their respective sites, whilst removing the 'www'.

Comment: I don't believe this will retain the URL structure, will it?  I would assume www.domain2.com/test1 would redirect to http://domain2.com, rather than the desired http://domain2.com/test1

Comment: Yes, it will retain the trailing URL fine.

Comment: This is great for SEO purposes. i.e. shifting link equity from www to non www or vice versa - which most people don't know, Google will penalize you for having duplicate content.

Answer (score 0):

You can have multiple VirtualHosts in a configuration file, so you should change your config to this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain1.com
    ServerAlias www.domain1.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName domain2.com
    ServerAlias www.domain2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

You can add another VirtualHost for each domain you want to do.

Comment: This simply sets up aliases for each domain, it does not redirect traffic from www.domain1.com to domain1.com.