# vhost setup to redirect multiple domains names and www version to single non-www domain

Tags: mod-rewrite, vhosts

I own two domain names:

- domain.com
- domain.net

…and I can't determine how to best setup the vhost code in order to achieve a few things:

1. If a visitor types in either of those two domain names, they go to `domain.net`
2. If a visitor types in either of those two domain names with www in front, they *still* go to `domain.net` (*without www*)
3. Keep file paths in place, so:

   - `domain.com/file.php` ends up going to `domain.net/file.php`
   - `www.domain.com/deeper/path/` ends up going to `domain.net/deeper/path/`
   - `www.domain.net` ends up going to `domain.net`
   - …and so on

I saw, in [this Q/A entry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/529334/how-to-dynamically-redirect-www-based-urls-to-non-www-urls-with-multiple-domains), what I *believe* is what I need, but I'm not 100% certain. Can somebody confirm (or correct) that this'll do exactly what I need:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  domain.net
    ServerAlias www.domain.net domain.com www.domain.com
    (the rest of the settings here)
</VirtualHost>
```

…is it as simple as that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As is, your vhost will accept your aliases and respond with the correct files but won't redirect the requests. If you want a canonical sub domain, you may want to add a few rewrite rules:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName  domain.net
    ServerAlias www.domain.net domain.com www.domain.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^domain\.net [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    !^$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)  http://domain.net/$1 [L,R=301]

    (the rest of the settings here)
</VirtualHost>
```

Check http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/rewrite_guide.html#canonicalhost for further explanations

Comment: Thank you sir! I'll try it this weekend and let you know how it goes for me.

Comment: Finally got a free moment to try it out, and it's perfect. Thanks again!